# Jquery template - else if construct

Tags: jquery, templates, if-statement

I was trying to use an "else if" statement inside the jquery template block.I have seen in other samples that instead of writing if else, we can just put else.But this is not working for me, its throwing syntax error on the template.can any one help pls?

The acutual way it should work is like

```
if(Amount == "")
{
-
}
else if(balance == "")
{
*
}
else
{
Amount
}
```

I have mentioned below the jquery template syntax which i wrote to acheive this.

```
<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB"><td onclick="test();">${CardNumber}</td><td>${PostDate}</td>
            <td>{{if (Amount == "")}}-
                {{else(balance == "")}}*                      
                {{else}}${Amount}
                {{/if}}
             </td>
             <td>${Description}</td></tr>
    </script>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be "return Amount" ?

Comment: did you manage to find the problem? If so, share your solution with the community.

Answer (score 52):

The syntax is correct as per [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-else/). Maybe try removing the `'('` parentheses?

```
{{if Amount == ""}}
   -
{{else balance == ""}}
   *                      
{{else}}
   ${Amount}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: strange man... are you *sure* you are importing the jQuery template javascript file?

Comment: Having the same issue - the same script is already doing some jquery-template stuff. But just realized it did not work because my if statement is executed in a iteration loop. Investigating still... will post a solution here if I find any

Comment: I found how to do an if statement on an item that is part of a series of item you are iterating through. see my answer

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when performing an if statement inside a loop, when doing the if statement on an item of the loop.

Assuming you are having an issue for the same reason (I see that your question includes some `td` and `tr` so you're probably iterating through items and displaying the their content in a table. Then here is my answer:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="jqTemplate">
 <ul>
      {{each data.messagetext}}
         <li>
             Message # ${$index+1}: &quot;${$value}&quot; |
             Test result: {{if $value}}exists{{else}}does not exist{{/if}}
         </li> 
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

notice the dollar sign in `{{if $value}}`, this is the trick on the regular `{{if value}}`

if you want to check the field of an item you are iterating on you can do `{{if $value.fieldname}}exists{{else}}does not exist{{/if}}`

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x2Tac/

jquery-template doc http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/template-tag-if

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is:

{{else [Condition]}}

Make sure that you import the jquery template js.